# Android glide load bitmap

Tags: android, caching, imageview, android-glide

In my app, i have an image view, the image content I get from the server is in the format of base64 encoded string. I store it locally and decode it to bitmap. This bitmap is loaded to the image view. This makes the app to scroll slow. 
Now I found the reason behind that is no caching is done for the bitmap. One recommended a solution to use glide. But I did not find any method to load bitmap using glide. I just found the following method

```
Glide.with(context).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(pollWebView);
```

can we load bitmap using glide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `File` to Glide.

`Glide.with(context).load(new File("your/file/name.jpg")).into(pollWebView);`

Comment: my image path is /data/data/com.inxed/dataImage/name.png but glide not loads the image from that path. why?

Comment: Add a `.listener()` to see why: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling

Comment: @Jyothish Send `"file://" + path`